# What should I use from init and systemd to create daemon for my service?

Tags: linux, service

What should be used from init and systemd to create daemon for a service. Heard that init is been removed from linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you don't need to change your program. You just need to write a .service file which describes how your daemon works. What's the command line to start it, how do you stop it, etcetera.

You can create a tighter integration, but the .service file remains the first step.

Comment: yeah, I won't need to change my program, but how one is better over another or there is no difference between both?

Comment: @SagarChoudhary: That's not a programming question, and it's also subjective. So I removed that part to prevent your question from being closed. Besides, as a software developer that usually is not your choice to make.

Comment: if i am writing my own service and i need to set up everything for it then I think it will be my decision to decide what to be used based on what offers better results over other.

Comment: @SagarChoudhary: I think you miss the point. There is only one process running under PID 1, and it is either init or systemd. That choice is not your to make, it depends on the Linux distribution. And all major distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, Red Hat, Fedora, Mint) have moved to systemd.

Comment: okay, I misunderstood your comment, sorry for it. yeah got it now